# Dynamic form selection in zeppelin with python

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I want to create a dynamic form in apache zeppelin with python interpreter. I wanto to show graph after the selection, by the user, of a value in a column. In the example below, i want to show graph after selection of a choice 'A','B','C','D' of example_1 column.

```
data = {'example_1':  ['B','A', 'B','C','D','B','C','C'],
        'example_2': ['X','Y','Z','Z','X','Y','X','Y'],
        'example_3': [2,1,5,5,3,2,1,1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['example_1','example_2','example_3'])

  example_1 example_2  example_3
0         B         X          2
1         A         Y          1
2         B         Z          5
3         C         Z          5
4         D         X          3
5         B         Y          2
6         C         X          1
7         C         Y          1
```

I'm able to use selection with mysql interpret, with the ${} in WHERE condition, but how can i do this in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try this and works fine>

```
z.show(df.loc[df["example_1"]==z.select("selection",[('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D')])])
```